# Cassandra backup restore does not display data

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, database-backups

I have taken Cassandra backup from one cluster and going to restore to another(new) cluster with same configuration.

1) I have copied backup to each node in cluster (different node with different server backup )
2) Copied data into correct location in data path

But when I log into CQLSH, data does not display. Restarting the nodes also did not work.

Comment: Did you try bouncing the node? Should help

Comment: Did you use nodetool snapshot to take the backups? And then did you try sstableloader to restore?

Answer (score 0):

For restoring clone cluster, you will have to export tokens from all Cassandra nodes and put them into new cassandra.yaml on each node. copy all the sstable per node after schema creation and start Cassandra services.